# Newly created build process parameters not showing up

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When I add a new parameter in the Process Parameter Metadata Editor, checkin my changes, and go back to edit the definition or queue a build from it, the parameter is not showing. Here is the parameter in the editor:

[image: new parameter not working]

Other custom parameters I added in the past show up fine. For example, this one shows up fine:

[image: this one works fine]

So..I would expect my new parameter to show up the same way this one works.

I tried closing and re-opening VS2013 (I have update 4) and changing to another build controller, but get same behavior. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parameter must be defined at the Build Arguments level (the place you found the Build Parameters Metadata).

[image]

Afterwards, the Metadata defines *how* it shows up, which editors it uses, and what description should be shown on it.

Answer (score 2):

That's about the *metadata*, but you need to add your parameter in the **Arguments** tab.
You will find it in the XAML Workflow editor at the bottom three buttons/tabs: **Variables**, **Arguments** and **Imports**.